# Python: dynamically binning the columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to bin the following fields using `for` loop in pandas.

```
KUNNR   Value_1    Value_2   Value_3    Value_4
1001     0         30         15         20
1002     1         10         10         31
1003     0         30         35         40
1004     0         10          0         32
1005     2         25         40         35
```

I am trying the following code:

```
df_cols = df.columns.tolist()
for c in df_cols:
  num = df[c].nunique()
  bin_s = np.linspace(start=df[c].min(),stop=df[c].max(),num = num)
  df[c] = pd.cut(df[c],bins=bin_s,labels=range(1,num),duplicates='drop')
```

But I am getting the `nan` in value_1 field.

Now my question is :

How to dynamically set that `num` in `np.linspace()` and `labels` in `pd.cut()` so that for each column the correct `num` and `lables` are decided automatically.

Comment: What if you just used `df[c].unique()` to help determine `num`, then have `labels` be `range(1,num)`?

Comment: I am just trying that only. Let me see.

Comment: @bug_spray:getting `nan` for Value_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
df_cols = df.columns.tolist()
for c in df_cols:
    num = df[c].nunique()
    df[c] = pd.cut(df[c].astype('int'), bins=num, labels=range(num), duplicates='drop')
```

I believe you were getting NaN values because, according to the docs for `pd.cut` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

> Passing an IntervalIndex for bins results in those categories exactly. Notice that values not covered by the IntervalIndex are set to NaN. 0 is to the left of the first bin (which is closed on the right), and 1.5 falls between two bins.

If you pass an integer to `bins`, though, it should separate everything evenly, removing the need to use `np.linspace`

Comment: Yes it has worked. Thanks a lot. However, if the `df[c].nunique()` is say 100, then `num=100`. Which is sometime cumbersome to manage.

Comment: You could cap it off at a desired value. For instance, if you wanted to have a maximum of 10 bins: `num = min(10, df[c].nunique())`